# How to implement filter by filter by search multiple property values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, lodash

I want to get the result based on what i have entered in the input field. This search can be filter by multiple keys like firstName, lastName, emailId.

This is my array of object,

```
var resData = [
            {
                firstName:"Jhon",
                lastName:"adam",
                emailId:"jhn12@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                firstName:"Kyle",
                lastName:"Miller",
                emailId:"kl12@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                firstName:"Jhonathan",
                lastName:"adam",
                emailId:"jadm12@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                firstName:"Lewis",
                lastName:"harber",
                emailId:"lewh12@gmail.com"
            }
        ];
```

Javascript code,

```
resData.filter(data, function(item){
                        item.map(function(list, i) {
                            if (list.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.state.inputValue.toLowerCase()) === -1 || list.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.state.inputValue.toLowerCase()) === -1 || list.emailId.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.state.inputValue.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
                                return;
                            }
                            console.log(list);
                        });

                    });
```

Comment: And how should the user enter multiple values? Is there a format, for example `firstname:Jhon emaiid:jhn12@gmail.com`? Or is it just a white-space separated list of strings: `jhon jhn12@gmail.com`?

Comment: Sounds like you want an autocomplete looking for matches in all values. What does the `map` do there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate through the keys and return true for the filter if some value is found.

```js
var resData = [{ firstName: "Jhon", lastName: "adam", emailId: "jhn12@gmail.com" }, { firstName: "Kyle", lastName: "Miller", emailId: "kl12@gmail.com" }, { firstName: "Jhonathan", lastName: "adam", emailId: "jadm12@gmail.com" }, { firstName: "Lewis", lastName: "harber", emailId: "lewh12@gmail.com" }],
    self = { state: { inputValue: 'adam' } },
    result = resData.filter(function (item) {
        return Object.keys(item).some(function (k) {
            return item[k].toLowerCase().indexOf(self.state.inputValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
    });
   
console.log(result);
```

With predefined keys

```js
var resData = [{ firstName: "Jhon", lastName: "adam", emailId: "jhn12@gmail.com" }, { firstName: "Kyle", lastName: "Miller", emailId: "kl12@gmail.com" }, { firstName: "Jhonathan", lastName: "adam", emailId: "jadm12@gmail.com" }, { firstName: "Lewis", lastName: "harber", emailId: "lewh12@gmail.com" }],
    self = { state: { inputValue: 'adam' } },
    result = resData.filter(function (item) {
        return ['firstName', 'lastName'].some(function (k) {
            return item[k].toLowerCase().indexOf(self.state.inputValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
    });
   
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can i define keys manually? Because some of the key values are null. So its returning error.

Answer (score 1):

```
var resData = [
        {
            firstName:"Jhon",
            lastName:"adam",
            emailId:"jhn12@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            firstName:"Kyle",
            lastName:"Miller",
            emailId:"kl12@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            firstName:"Jhonathan",
            lastName:"adam",
            emailId:"jadm12@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            firstName:"Lewis",
            lastName:"harber",
            emailId:"lewh12@gmail.com"
        }
    ];

var search = function(text) {
  text = text.toLowerCase();
  return resData.filter(x => x.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) >= 0 
       || x.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) >= 0 
       || x.emailId.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) >= 0);
}

console.log(search("Adam"));
```

Comment: While this is *waaay* better than the OP's version in terms of performance and readability, not sure it actually answers the question.

Comment: How so? This will return the elements that match the search text based of the different key values. That was my understanding of his question.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the problem, it isn't at all clear what the question *is*.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to search by any key...

```js
var resData = [{
  firstName: "Jhon",
  lastName: "adam",
  emailId: "jhn12@gmail.com"
}, {
  firstName: "Kyle",
  lastName: "Miller",
  emailId: "kl12@gmail.com"
}, {
  firstName: "Jhonathan",
  lastName: "adam",
  emailId: "jadm12@gmail.com"
}, {
  firstName: "Lewis",
  lastName: "harber",
  emailId: "lewh12@gmail.com"
}];

//var searchString = self.state.inputValue.toLowerCase();
var searchString = "adam".toLowerCase();

// filter the data
var filteredData = resData.filter(function(item) {
  // for each item int he array, check each key value
  for (key in item) {
    // if the key value matches the search string then return true
    if (item[key].toLowerCase() == searchString) return true;
  }
  // if we get here that means none of the values in the item were a match so return false
  return false;
});

console.log(filteredData);
```